# How Cassandra data sync works between new node to existing cluster?

Tags: datastax, cassandra-2.1

I have a existing cassandra cluster. To add a new node, Should the newly added cassandra node be empty ? What if it already has some data ?

Will the newly added node's data be replicated to nodes of existing cluster ?

> Cassandra Version : 2.1.8

In my use case I am trying to join 2 nodes (both with data) to a cluster with replication factor 2. Eventually will each node have data of the other node ?

Comment: You have not mentioned the cassandra version.  Would recommend you to go through the following documentations.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeVnodesUsing_c.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

Comment: Added the version now